# AWX custom virtual environments not showing up

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower, ansible-awx

I've been following instructions for setting up custom virtual environments on AWX.

Steps so far:

1. Created virtualenvs at `/var/lib/awx/venv/py2` and `/var/lib/awx/venv/py3`
2. Sent authenticated `PATCH` request to update venv path setting

   - Endpoint: `http://localhost:8052/api/v2/settings/system`
   - Body: `{ "CUSTOM_VENV_PATHS": ["/var/lib/awx/venv/"] }`

The `/api/v2/config` endpoint never shows anything but the default virtualenv.

```
"custom_virtualenvs": [
  "/var/lib/awx/venv/ansible/"
]
```

Other things I've tried:

- Restarting the AWX task container
- Setting `CUSTOM_VENV_PATHS = ['/var/lib/awx/venv/']` in `/etc/tower/settings.py`

**What am I missing?**

Resources:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/upgrade-migration-guide/virtualenv.html

https://github.com/ansible/awx/blob/devel/docs/custom_virtualenvs.md

https://github.com/ansible/awx/issues/515

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to add the virtual environments to both the AWX web image and the AWX task image.

The virtual environments weren't registering because I had only added them to the task image. Once I added them to both the task and web images I was able to use the virtual environments without running the PATCH request or providing any additional configuration. (This is because I put the virtual environments in the default directory `/var/lib/awx/venv/`).